# Is there a name for the operation which is the union of two sets, but keeps duplicates?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a name for the operation $*$ such that, for example, if $A = \{a, b\}$ and $B = \{a, b, c\}$,
$$A * B = \{a, a, b, b, c \}\text{?}$$
I.e., it is the union of $A$ and $B$ including duplicates?

*Context*. This would be particularly useful for nonparametric statistics, in particular, for the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test.

Comment: How this could be useful, sorry? Anyway, just threat sets as multisets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no notion of duplicates in regular sets. A set $\{1\}$  is the same as a set $\{1, 1\}$. You are probably interested in [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). The union of multisets behaves just as you would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a notion for that: the *disjoint union* of $A$ and $B$, denoted $A\coprod B$, which is the *coproduct* in the category of sets, i.e. it is the soltuion of the following *universal problem*:

Given two sets $A,B$, find a set $C$ and a pair of maps $i_A\colon A\to C$, $i_B\colon B\to C$, such that,for any set $X$ and pair of maps  $j_A\colon A\to X$, $j_B\colon B\to X$, there exists a unique map $h\colon C\to X$ such that $$j_A=h\circ i_A,\quad j_B=h\circ i_B.$$

It is used in defining the direct limit of an inductive system (another universal problem!) of sets, rings, modules, &c.

Technically, the construction consists in considering copies of $A$ and $B$ with an index: $A_1=\{\,(a,1)\mid a\in A\,\}$,  $B_2=\{\,(b,2)\mid b\in B\,\}$ so we're sure $A_1$  and $B_2$ are disjoint, and setting:
$$A\coprod B=A_1\cup B_2.$$